# Simplify Complicated If statements

Tags: c#

Well, I have a Form that receives the Employee's level and enable some options depending on his level using a bunch of `Checkboxes`. However the problem i am facing is that for my application's logic there is specific level range for every option to be enabled so i created an Ugly `IF` range checking statements that i am sure there is a better way to achieve.

**CODE**:

```
if (level >= 1 && level < 3) {
    _items[0].Enabled = true;
    _items[1].Enabled = false;
    _items[2].Enabled = false;
    _items[3].Enabled = false;
    _items[4].Enabled = false;
    _items[5].Enabled = false;
    _items[6].Enabled = false;
    _items[7].Enabled = false;
}
else if (level >= 3 && level < 5) {
    _items[0].Enabled = true;
    _items[1].Enabled = true;
    _items[2].Enabled = false;
    _items[3].Enabled = false;
    _items[4].Enabled = false;
    _items[5].Enabled = false;
    _items[6].Enabled = false;
    _items[7].Enabled = false;
}
else if (level >= 5 && level < 7) {
    _items[0].Enabled = true;
    _items[1].Enabled = true;
    _items[2].Enabled = true;
    _items[3].Enabled = false;
    _items[4].Enabled = false;
    _items[5].Enabled = false;
    _items[6].Enabled = false;
    _items[7].Enabled = false;
}
else if (level >= 7 && level < 9) {
    _items[0].Enabled = true;
    _items[1].Enabled = true;
    _items[2].Enabled = true;
    _items[3].Enabled = true;
    _items[4].Enabled = false;
    _items[5].Enabled = false;
    _items[6].Enabled = false;
    _items[7].Enabled = false;
}
else if (level >= 9 && level < 11) {
    _items[0].Enabled = true;
    _items[1].Enabled = true;
    _items[2].Enabled = true;
    _items[3].Enabled = true;
    _items[4].Enabled = true;
    _items[5].Enabled = false;
    _items[6].Enabled = false;
    _items[7].Enabled = false;
}
else if (level >= 11 && level < 13) {
    _items[0].Enabled = true;
    _items[1].Enabled = true;
    _items[2].Enabled = true;
    _items[3].Enabled = true;
    _items[4].Enabled = true;
    _items[5].Enabled = true;
    _items[6].Enabled = false;
    _items[7].Enabled = false;
}
else if (level >= 13 && level < 15) {
    _items[0].Enabled = true;
    _items[1].Enabled = true;
    _items[2].Enabled = true;
    _items[3].Enabled = true;
    _items[4].Enabled = true;
    _items[5].Enabled = true;
    _items[6].Enabled = true;
    _items[7].Enabled = false;
}
else if (level >= 15 && level < 17) {
    _items[0].Enabled = true;
    _items[1].Enabled = true;
    _items[2].Enabled = true;
    _items[3].Enabled = true;
    _items[4].Enabled = true;
    _items[5].Enabled = true;
    _items[6].Enabled = true;
    _items[7].Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Although it's long to type, there is nothing really bad about this if statement.  It is not redundant other than setting item 0 which is the same in each case.

Comment: @RacerNerd i am just carious to know what are the better posisbilities to achieve the same goal

Comment: If length is the issue, you could call a function in each block that set the values.

Comment: Also i feel a little retarded when i create long redundant code. Can you make it a little bit clear what you mean by blocks ?

Comment: By a block I mean if(comparison){BLOCK HERE}

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can simplify this with a little math:

```
int on = (level+1)/2;
for (int i = 0 ; i != 8 ; i++) {
    _items[i].Enabled = (i < on);
}
```

The first line converts a number in the range from 1 to 16, inclusive, to a number in the range from 1 to 8, inclusive. Then the loop goes through all items, and enables as many of them as is indicated by the value of the `on` variable computed earlier.

Comment: amazing! i love solutions like this!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : I HATE MATH :D My bad xD this is amazing.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: i am taking a long time to understand this little math, i am so STUPID :D

Comment: Clever, but not self-documenting.

Comment: @RacerNerd "inefficient"? I don't see any such problem with this code.

Comment: @RacerNerd Do some measurements and come back with the numbers.

Comment: Not worth it.. if people like this, wonderful.  Nice solution.

Comment: Downvote as this solves the immediate question in an admittedly clever way, but is extremely domain specific to the OP's question. For this answer to continue to function correctly, the OP has to both maintain the order of their controls in the items List, as well as maintain a 1-to-N correspondence of privilege level to controls. I believe SO answers should inform the OP when their methodology is flawed to begin with... I have added an answer below.

Comment: @AndrewHanlon Trust me on this one, you simply cannot go wrong converting eighty lines of code to four lines of code.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight In most cases I wouldn't disagree, except when it hides a poor architecture. If the OP's question was only how to simplify an if statement when there are known ranges then this would be great. But he explicitly showed what he was doing and why, and it is obviously flawed.

Comment: @AndrewHanlon I do not agree that his code is "obviously flawed": I did not see enough code to pass such a judgement. A connection between the numeric value of `level` and availability of certain visual items can very well be cast in stone in accordance with OP's domain. At the very least, I do not think that I am in a good position to question his decision.

Answer (score 6):

You (might) lose performance, but its arguably more readable. Choose your poison! The performance difference depends on how often this is called.

```
if(level >= 1) {
    _items[0].Enabled = level >= 1;
    _items[1].Enabled = level >= 3;
    _items[2].Enabled = level >= 5;
    _items[3].Enabled = level >= 8;
    _items[4].Enabled = level >= 9;
    _items[5].Enabled = level >= 11;
    _items[6].Enabled = level >= 13;
    _items[7].Enabled = level >= 15;
}
```

Comment: In case it is not clear, Vache is saying this is inefficient code, but easier to maintain.

Comment: +1 However you may look at @dasblinkenlight code it is very amazing in just 3 lines :D.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to say indeed, but the inefficiency won't be noticeable unless this is called in a tight loop.

Comment: I don't think it's the same. For instance in OP's example _items[7] is enabled only when level is 15 or 16. In your solution _items[7] is enabled at all level under 17. Am I right?

Comment: @Mitulátbáti You're right! I had the logic reversed. I corrected it

Answer (score 4):

One option, you could use a `Dictionary` to store the range for each checkbox-index:

```
private static Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, int>> _Ranges = new Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, int>>() 
{ 
    { 0, Tuple.Create(1, 3) },{ 1, Tuple.Create(3, 5) },{ 2, Tuple.Create(5, 7) },{ 3, Tuple.Create(7, 9) },
    { 4, Tuple.Create(9, 11) },{ 5, Tuple.Create(11, 13) },{ 6, Tuple.Create(13, 15) },{ 7, Tuple.Create(15, 17) }
};
```

Now this concise code should do the same:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
{
    var range = _Ranges[i];
    _items[i].Enabled = level >= range.Item1 && level < range.Item2;
}
```

You could also create a custom `Range` class which encapsulates this logic.

Comment: Doesn't even need a dictionary here, a List would do.

Comment: Nothing wrong with dictionary. Just saying `List<Tuple<int, int>>` would work also.

Comment: @Magnus: good point, however, a dictionary could  still be used if the logic changes and   the index shouldn't be used as   key anymore but   for example the control. A dictionary is just the most natural lookup collection.

Answer (score 1):

Turn it around to something like this instead:

```
_items[0].Enabled = ( level >= 1 && level < 17 );
....
```

Comment: Setting this using this technique is inefficient because the comparison will have to be done every time the value is set rather than one time for the whole block

Comment: If you were to do this a couple of million times in a tight loop, sure. No need to try to optimize something that isn't a bottleneck.

Comment: If you don't want to pay attention to the details that's your choice.

Comment: There's a difference between paying attention to details and wasting time and money by spending time on things that doesn't make any difference. I'd say that maintainability is alot more important in this case - and you get that from simplicity.

Comment: In that case, you would tell the OP to use his code rather than yours since it would be a waste of time and money to change his because it is efficient and readable.

Comment: Actually, his code isn't readable. It's too long and too hard to change. If he wants to change the range on one of the items, he'd have to change it in 8 places. My code would be 8 lines, each line caring for each item. Easier to read, easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the elses:

```
_items[0].Enabled = false;
_items[1].Enabled = false;
_items[2].Enabled = false;
_items[3].Enabled = false;
_items[4].Enabled = false;
_items[5].Enabled = false;
_items[6].Enabled = false;
_items[7].Enabled = false;
if (level >= 1) 
    _items[0].Enabled = true;
if (level >= 3) 
    _items[1].Enabled = true;
if (level >= 5) 
    _items[2].Enabled = true;
if (level >= 7) 
    _items[3].Enabled = true;
if (level >= 9) 
    _items[4].Enabled = true;
if (level >= 11) 
    _items[5].Enabled = true;
if (level >= 13) 
    _items[6].Enabled = true;
if (level >= 15 && level < 17) 
    _items[7].Enabled = true;
```

Comment: This is also less efficient than the original example since it requires that 8 comparisons are made each time the code executes.

Comment: @RacerNerd True, but I'm assuming the permissions only get computed once. If, however, MAXIMUM EFFICIENCY is important, the `if` statements could be nested.

Answer (score 0):

Your security levels seem to be perfectly overlapping

So could you not do something as simple as

```
 _items[0].Enabled = (level >= 1);
 _items[1].Enabled = (level >= 3);
 _items[2].Enabled = (level >= 5);
```

etc?

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to suggest that this method of enabling / disabling the form components is flawed to begin with. And the top answer only solves this narrow case, where the items in the form are ordered and correspond 1 to N with the privilege levels...

If this application uses any kind of presentation separation scenario (MVC, MVVM, etc.) then this should certainly be done differently through databinding.

But even in the most naive case, a better way to handle this would be to add a privilege level flag to the checkboxes (maybe using their Tag in WinForms, an attached property in WPF, etc.) and loop through them comparing against the current privilege of the user. A dictionary of checkbox to privilege level would also work nicely:

```
    Dictionary<Control, int> RequiredControlPrivilege;

    foreach(var item in _items)
    {
        if(RequiredControlPrivilege.Contains(item)
        {
            item.Enabled = RequiredControlPrivilege[item] >= CurrentLevel
        }
        else
        {
            item.Enabled = false //Default to false or change to true...
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a fine example of how to make a mountain out of a molehill. To me, overbuilding something right from the start is always a bad idea, with no exceptions.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I appreciate your argument, but if it mattered enough that the OP needed to clean-up the if statements, then it is likely going to need to be maintained - something his methodology does not permit easily.

Comment: There are many reasons to clean up the code. One of them is when the approach isn't right; another one is when the code isn't right. To me, these two are very much independent. With eight `if`s that look like octuplets, the question of how to simplify it is very reasonable, regardless of whether the overall approach is right or wrong.